# jquery menu only appears on firefox chrome and ie9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

Ok i am currently putting together a site for my mrs using html and experimenting with jquery. Everything works fantastically well until anything to do with ie6,7,or 8 is involved. at which point no navigation menu shows.

```
enter code here
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        // set opacity to nill on page load
        $("ul#menu span").css("opacity","0");
        // on mouse over
        $("ul#menu span").hover(function () {
            // animate opacity to full
            $(this).stop().animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, "slow");
        },
        // on mouse out
        function () {
            // animate opacity to nill
            $(this).stop().animate({
                opacity: 0
            }, "slow");
        });
    });
</script>
```

this is the scripti have used i copied it from a tutorial as i have not had much experience. i beleive it is something to do with the opacity values but cannot find what i need to fix it any help would be great thx.

P.s - the jquery i am using is 1.6.2min.js

the site is http://www.emerrillsphotography.co.uk

Comment: And what is the link to the tutorial?

Comment: http://www.shopdev.co.uk/blog/animated-menus-using-jquery/

Answer (score 2):

I believe that opacity as a CSS property is not properly supported by Internet Explorer versions before 9.

You must use something like:

```
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
```

for IE8 and

```
filter: alpha(opacity=50);
```

for IE7

http://acidmartin.wordpress.com/2008/11/28/setting-opacity-and-other-filters-in-internet-explorer-8/

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#transparency

Answer (score 0):

Try using fadeIn -Out instead:

Okay. I think jQuery fadeIn/-Out functions do what you want. Are pretty sure the take care of the cross-browser issue by using opacity.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    // jQuery fadeIn/-Out fading out an element and at the end sets display = block/none
    // fadeOut(0) means fading out all at once. same as .hide();
    // Hiding the span:
    $("ul#menu span").fadeOut(0);
    // Now is the span element's display none and therefore not hittable.
    // So we have to hover the a tag instead witch is the wrapper around the span
    $("ul#menu a").hover(function () {
        // this = a tag in HTMLelement -> find span tag -> stop animation (if any) . fadeIn("slow"); You can change "slow" out with a number eg. 564 -> 564 mil.sec.
        $(this).find("span").stop().fadeIn("slow");
    },function () {
        // this -> find span tag -> stop animation (if any) . fadeOut("slow");
        $(this).find("span").stop().fadeOut("slow");
    });
});
</script>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: ok tried the fade in/out option and it stopped the animation in every browser although can't test in ie 6,7,8 until around 4pm but the transition was the whole point of the jquery, and thank you for your quick response

Comment: Me and my stupid here you go love how do those tabs look? can't get the css to work correctly either but i not sure how much of this is due to my lack of knowledge on jquery - at a guess - all of it

Comment: so use the above code but replace the ul#menu span with ul#menu a? sorry for sounding dumb :(

Comment: Already changed it for you :) See example above. Hope you understand, and we all have to start somewhere...

Comment: :( ok now the animation works again - but only works the first time they are hovered over and still a no go in ie8 - ie no menu at all. so assuming this then i presume ie 6 + 7 are broke also. Sry for taking up your time. why couldn't microsoft just make the browsers work like all the others lol - would i be better for now resorting to what i know and making a html/css version of the tabs until i can figure this out?